# what to take as n in complexity of algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, big-o, time-complexity

**What have i done before on this topic:**

I have been stuck on this topic for quite a long time. I've read several examples of calculating the complexity of a simple algorithm in "Algorithms in Java" and Adam Drozdek's book and have searched the forums but i could not find this question.

**The problem:**

In some books such as "Algorithms in Java", for calculating time complexity of an algorithm, a certain statement is taken as n. But in another book of "Adam Drozdek", the number of times a loop is run is taken as n. So if I calculate complexity with taking one n, then in the other book, n is taken as something else and hence my calculated complexity becomes wrong. example is given below. So how can we universally agree on complexity of the same program?

**Example**

There is an example of sequential search.
Here is the code.

```
static int search(int a[], int v, int l, int r)   { 
    int i;     
    for (i = l; i <= r; i++)       
        if (v == a[i]) return i;     
    return -1;
} `
```

considering the worst case:

I took r as equal to n. so the loop runs n times...

1)comparison and increment and comparison runs n times so that is 3n.

2) initialization and declaration and return -1 runs 1 times so that is 3.

so the equation becomes

3n+ 3
and complexity is O(n).
but the book is considering the no. of comparisons as n and it has calculated the complexity from that view and hence it turns out to be n.

Comment: Usually, total searchable elements is considered n. In your example, the worst case complexity should be O(n). Basically, 3n+3 and n are the same order... O(n).

Comment: Thanks!So as long as the big O of the complexity is same, it does not matter how one has calculated it?

Comment: Meh, big-O notation just sets an upper bound, so just say it's O([BusyBeaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver)(N)) and you'll always be right. :)

Comment: :) It does matter how it is computed, but as long as you get the order right, i.e n doesn't become nlogn, n^2 etc. , you'll be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no disagreement.

The algorithm has linear runtime complexity. It takes twice as long for a range double the size.

You both agree that complexity is O(n). Both in terms of number of iterations (the book) and in terms of number of machine instructions (you). Your two ways of counting should be roughly equivalent in gauging the time it takes to run (which is what runtime complexity is about).

Answer (score 4):

I think you have it a bit backwards:

> In some books such as "Algorithms in Java", for calculating time complexity of an algorithm, a certain statement is taken as n. But in another book of "Adam Drozdek", the number of times a loop is run is taken as n.

I don't think that is correct.

The true `N` is really some scaling variable for the problem.  For example, it might be the length of a String if you are analysing a string search, or the number of elements in a collection if you are analysing a collection operation.

What those examples that you have found is that there is a relationship between the number of times the "certain statement" or "the loop" body is executed and the scaling variable.  Note that there can be more than one scaling variable, and that the scaling variable is not necessarily one of the algorithm's formal parameters.  (Hint!!)

---

In your example, you have found that there is a relationship between the value of `r` and the number of times that the loop is executed.  So in this case, `r` would be the problem / algorithm's scaling variable.

(Actually, you've made a mistake in your reasoning.  The number of iterations of the loop is NOT proportional to `r`.  Not even in the worst case.  Think some more about it!!)

Comment: My mistake I confused 'l' with '1'. So n= r-l+1 :)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by Stephen that the thing that matters is scaling and how your algorithm uses that scalable entity.

Quoting your example:

```
static int search(int a[], int v, int l, int r)   { 
    int i;     
    for (i = l; i <= r; i++)       
        if (foo(a)) return something;     
    return -1;
}
```

If your comparison uses the scalable entity i.e the array to make some decision then that particular value will contribute to the complexity.

In the same way if you are doing the same amount of computation in the comparison function regardless of any scalable entity, then it does not contribute. For example if the function foo always used lets say 5 machine intruction to perform its job, then it is basically a constant operation.

In your case the comparison is just a single operation everytime , hence will not change the O(n) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the terminology "complexity" (and overloading of the term) may be causing the confusion.

The `3n + 3` is a more accurate description of the complexity of a program.  But, in computer science, we rarely care about the `3n` vs `n` or the "+ 3" vs "+ 0" because (a) the big-O complexity is far more important, and (b) when the big-O complexity is the same, many other factors come into play to distinguish algorithms.  For example, the "+ 3" statements could each be very expensive operations or cheap, depending on just what they do.  In those cases, actually measuring the timing of the code under test, or live production, gives better results when comparing algorithms with the same big-O complexity.

Because we rarely care about those constants when discussing complexity of an algorithm, we often interchange the term complexity with the big-O complexity of an algorithm.

By the way, the `n` is the input value that drives the number of iterations of an algorithm.  Other than that, it can really be anything - it is not limited to being an actual variable in the program.  For example, a program that loops on reading input from a file will have `n` = the number of inputs read from the file.